# babel-loader, webpack, ES2015 modules: "Element type is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Github repo with everything in: https://github.com/b-paul/react-lifecycle

Update 12/18: A large part of the problem was the npm commands used to run the project. I had noticed that `npm build` was not successful, but `npm start` reported building OK. Full answer below on why that didn't work as expected. The rest of this question is being kept for posterity.

---

I'm having trouble with basic setup for my first webpack project. I'm using React and Babel, and the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [ path.resolve('./js/app.js'),
           'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080' ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./js/build'),
    filename: 'app.min.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-1', 'es2015']
        },
        include: path.resolve('js/') } ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

`js/app.js`

```
import Lifecycle from './components/lifecycle';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

var shell = document.createElement('div');
shell.className = 'app-shell';
document.body.appendChild(shell);
render(<Lifecycle />, shell);
```

`js/components/lifecycle.js`

```
import React from 'react';

class Lifecycle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello, world</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Lifecycle;
```

The above builds without errors, but it won't render "Hello, world". I'm getting the error, "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined." in the browser console.

I can trace this as far as some generated babel code that tries to check if my module `Lifecycle` is an ES6 module (babel recognizes it as such) and expects it to have a property `default` on the internal module object (it doesn't). Here is that generated code:

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

  'use strict';

  var _lifecycle = __webpack_require__(1);

  var _lifecycle2 = _interopRequireDefault(_lifecycle);

  var _react = __webpack_require__(2);

  var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

  var _reactDom = __webpack_require__(159);

  function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

  (0, _reactDom.render)(_react2.default.createElement(_lifecycle2.default, null), document.body);

/***/ }
```

Final note: I referenced https://github.com/code0wl/react-example-es2015 several times for setup, and I can clone and build that example repo into a working app with no problems. I'm realize that I must've missed some essential part of what's happening in that repo, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should have been called "why won't my NPM scripts update my bundle."

At some point early in development, I had successfully bundled my code with webpack. That bundle was on disk as `js/build/app.min.js`. After that point, I thought I was using NPM scripts from `package.json` to rebuild the app with each change, but in-browser, I was still getting the old behavior (from the original bundle). I missed two facts:

**Fact 1:** [`npm build`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build) is a recognized NPM command, but it does *not* invoke `scripts.build` from `package.json`. As in @zhongjie-wu 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347250/1517965), I needed to do `npm run build`. `npm start`, on the other hand, *does* invoke `scripts.start`, which successfully built a bundle with `webpack-dev-server`.

**Fact 2:** `webpack-dev-server` does not recognize `output.path` from the webpack config file as part of the route when serving the rebuilt bundle. Because of this, given the configuration I used, `webpack` builds to `/js/build/app.min.js`, but `webpack-dev-server` serves that bundle from memory as `/app.min.js`. Since my HTML references the original, I didn't see the dev server bundle.

Answer (score 1):

works for me

```
git clone https://github.com/b-paul/react-lifecycle.git
cd react-lifecycle.git
npm install
npm run build
npm run start
# go to http://localhost:8090/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there are reason for creating your app's container div dynamically in `app.js` rather than just putting it in `index.html`?  I cloned your repo and got the app to build by making the following changes:

**index.html:**

```
<body>
   <div id="app-shell"></div>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="js/build/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Lifecycle from './components/lifecycle';

render(<Lifecycle />, document.getElementById('app-shell'));
```

I think the `“Element type is invalid”` error was a red herring.  Prior to that I was seeing:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).warning @
>   app.min.js:2233createElement @ app.min.js:19531(anonymous function) @
>   app.min.js:61__webpack_require__ @ app.min.js:20(anonymous function) @
>   app.min.js:40(anonymous function) @ app.min.js:43 app.min.js:2233
>   Warning: render(): Rendering components directly into document.body is
>   discouraged, since its children are often manipulated by third-party
>   scripts and browser extensions. This may lead to subtle reconciliation
>   issues. Try rendering into a container element created for your app.

Which is likely due to the way you are creating the shell element in `app.js`...

Answer (score 0):

**Layout.js**

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Layout">

      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

**.babelrc**
need add stage-1 preset for try transpiling classes

```
    {
      "presets": ["stage-1", "es2015", "react"],
      "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
    }
```

**and entry file need doing ES5 export:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'));
}

module.exports = Layout;
```

its working for me